# Функция выдает ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np

def human_turn(arr, stroka, stolbik):
  for i in range(3):
    for j in range (3):
      arr[stroka - 1][stolbik - 1] = 1

def output(arr):
  for i in range(3):
    for j in range (3):
      if arr[i][j] == 0:
        print(" ")
      elif arr[i][j] == 1:
        print("x")
      elif arr[i][j] == 2:
        print("o")
    "\n"
def poisk(arr, stroka, stolbik, u):
  c = 0
  for i in range (3):
    for j in range (3):
      if arr[i][j] == 0:
        stroka = i 
        stolbik = j
  for j in range (3):
    for i in range (3):
      if arr[i][j] == u:
        c += 1
    if c == 2:
      for i in range (3):
        if arr[i][j] ==  0:
          stroka = i
          stolbik = j
  c = 0
  for j in range (3):
    for i in range (3):
      if arr[i][j] == 0 and i == j:
        stroka = i
        stolbik = j
  for j in range (3):
    for i in range (3):
      if arr[i][j] == 0 and i + j == 2:
        stroka = i
        stolbik = j
  if c == 2:
    for j in range (3):
      for i in range (3):
        if arr[i][j] == 0 and i + j == 2:
          stroka = i
          stolbik = j


a = 0
b = 0
a1 = 0
b1 = 0
xN = 0
yN = 0
c = 0
arr = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range (3):
  for j in range (3):
    arr[i][j] = 0
output(arr)
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
human_turn(a, b, arr[3][3])
if a == 2 and b == 2:
  arr[0][0] = 2
else:
  arr[1][1] = 2
output(arr)

a1 = a
b1 = b

a = int(input())
b = int(input())

xN = -1
yN = -1 

poisk(arr, xN, yN, 2)
if xN == -1:
  poisk(arr, xN, yN, 1)
  if (xN == -1 and arr[2][0] == 1 and arr[0][2] == 1) or (arr[0][0] == 1 and arr[2][2] ==  1):
    arr[2][1] = 2
  elif (xN == -1 and arr[1][0] == 1 and arr[1][2] == 1) or (arr[0][1] == 1 and arr[2][1] ==  1):
    arr[0][0] = 2
  elif arr[1][2] == 1 and arr[2][1] == 1:
    arr[2][2] = 2
  elif arr[1][2] == 1 and arr[0][1] == 1:
    arr[0][2] = 2
  elif arr[0][1] == 1 and arr[1][0] == 1:
    arr[0][0] = 2
  elif arr[1][0] == 1 and arr[2][1] == 1:
    arr[2][0] = 2
  elif arr[2][2] == arr[1][1]:
    arr[2][0] = 2
  elif (xN == -1 and a != b) and (a == 1 and b == 3):
    arr[b-1][a-1] = 2
  elif (xN == -1 and a != b) and (a1 == 1 and b1 == 3):
    arr[b1-1][a1-1] = 2
  elif xN == -1 and (a == b or b1 == a1):
    arr[2][0] = 2
  else:
    arr[xN][yN] = 2
else:
  arr[xN][yN] = 2
  output(arr)
  print("BOT WIN")
output(arr)
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
human_turn(arr, a, b)
xN = -1
yN = -1
poisk(arr, xN, yN, 2)
if xN==-1:
  poisk(arr,xN,yN,1)                    
  if xN==-1 and arr[2][2]==0:
    arr[2][2] = 2 
  elif xN==-1 and arr[0][0]==0:
    arr[0][0]=2                    
  elif xN==-1 and arr[0][1]==0:
    arr[0][1]=2                     
  elif xN==-1 and arr[1][2]==0:
    arr[1][2]=2
  elif xN==-1 and arr[2][1]==0:
    arr[2][1]=2                    
  elif xN==-1 and arr[1][0]==0:
    arr[1][0]=2                  
  else:           
    arr[xN][yN]
```

arr-массив, заданный np.zeros((3,3))

Comment: Все работает.  Приведи полный код.

Comment: прикрепил, проверьте

Comment: Я запустил код и ничего не происходит, кроме печати нескольких пустых строк.

Comment: это крестики нолики, введите например:1 "enter:" 1

Comment: выходит совсем другая ошибка.

Comment: в 67 строке нужно убрать [3][3] и будет выводить ту

Answer (score 0):

Функция `human_turn(arr, stroka, stolbik)` подразумевает первым аргументов двумерный список, а в ее вызове первым аргументом идет число.